# How do I secure the connection to this battery (CR1616)?

Tags: batteries, contact, pad

I'm replacing the batter in a Game Boy Advance game cartridge.

[image: Inside the Game Boy Advance cartridge.]

(Don't mind the bad solder job; the iron isn't handling well.)

I've gotten it to work, but the battery is held down with very little force; so I don't have much confidence in the actual connection between the bottom pad and the positive-side of the battery. I feel like one bad shake and the battery might (even if momentarily) disconnect on the bottom side.

I tried shaping the bottom pad using some small pliers, but that clearly wasn't enough. Does anyone else have any ideas on how to make a more solid connection on the bottom side?

I have electrical tape, pliers, soldering iron, and even some solder tabs.

[image: Solder tabs.]

Here's a different angle, in case it helps:

[image: Battery - bottom side.]

Here, the pad and battery only touch at a single point. It's slightly better when there is pressure pushing the battery down.

- NOTE: If anyone feels this belongs in a different site, please feel free to move it.

Answer (score 2):

Batteries are often spot welded.
How about buying [a battery with the tabs](https://console5.com/store/panasonic-cr1616-lithium-battery-with-solder-tabs-pins-game-boy.html)?

Comment: I'd like to be able to remove the battery in the future without having to de-solder.

Answer (score 1):

A  BH600  coin cell holder is not expensive.

https://media.digikey.com/photos/Memory%20Protection%20Photos/BH600.jpg

Comment: Not possible with the limited space inside the GBA cartridge.

Comment: Then use a thin high adhesive strength polyamide tape or a construction tape made in Canada called Tuck Tape. (red) (not Scotch Tape or duck Tape) and gently pre- bend the top stainless steel for more contact force then insert battery and tape down under pressure inside cartridge.

Comment: When you say "top stainless steel", you're talking about the top tab that holds the battery in the picture. Correct?

Comment: you got it.....using a pair of small needle nose pliers or tweezers to protect the solder joint.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a tutorial where a guy put a piece of electrical tape underneath the bottom tab, put the new battery in, straightened out the top tab with a flat head screwdriver, laid  it on top of the battery then tightly wrapped the tape on.  It didn’t look pretty, but it worked.